# Are trigger limits applied for every flow

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder, governorlimits

I'm checking an integration to a SF org and it seems to be hitting "Apex CPU time limit exceeded" and it is brining up different sources. Sometimes it breaks during a process builder action from a third party app, other times it is some custom code, but the common theme is it is happening on processes connected with the Account object.

Is it possible that due to a badly written Account handler in account trigger the first 10 flows that are creating are taking too long, so when it gets to the latter ones it just times out even if they are written ok, or each flow has separate limits counter?

Answer (score 3):

Limits are applied for one transaction. So if you have written a multiple trigger, multiple flow and process builder on account then governor limit is applied on execution of all the above actions.

```
processbuilders+ triggers+ flows < governor limit
```

Even managed package code and process builders count in governor limit.